# Node JS file transfer via Request Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, request

I am creating a node server to which files can be uploaded an then sent to a storage server which is also using node. 
To do this i am using this method described on the Form-Data module page:

```
var formData = {
  my_field: 'my_value',
  my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/unicycle.jpg'),
};

request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

My Problem is that when i try to write the file on the storage server it creates a text file with the content [object Object].

Here is my code:

main.js

```
var form = new formData();
form = {
        'oldFileName': oldName,
        'newFileName': newName,
        'file': fs.createReadStream(FILEPATH),
    };

    request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:9001/upload', form: form}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
    });
```

storage.js

```
app.post('/upload', function(req,res){
    //Filenames are displayed without problem
    console.log(req.body.newFileName);
    console.log(req.body.oldFileName);

    fs.writeFile('./testing/' + req.body.newFileName, req.body.file, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
})
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: I think that you have to use `multer` or similar library to accept `multipart/form-data` in `storage.js`

Comment: I tried that(sorry should have mentioned it), but `multer` did not appear to recognize the File in the constructed Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `formData` in `form` option of `request` that changes the content to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`instead of `multipart/form-data`.

**app.js**

```
var form = {
    'oldFileName': oldName,
    'newFileName': newName,
    'file': fs.createReadStream(FILEPATH),
};

request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:9001/upload', formData: form}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
});
```

Also, to parse `multipart/form-data`, you have to use `multer` or similar library, `body-parser` doesn't work in that case. Please find following working `storage.js` code for saving file.

**storage.js**

```
  var multer  = require('multer')
  var upload = multer({
     storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, './testing/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, req.body.newFileName);
        }
     })
  }).single('file');

 app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if(err){
          return res.send(err);
        } else{
          return res.send("Upload successfully");
        }
    });
 });
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, wrapping the [object Object] within a JSON.stringify() method should reveal the literal string content of the objects.

In my situation I was using the NodeJS Library for YouTube video uploads, following OAuth2.0 protocol.

Within this standard, you post your Client ID and Client Secret to authenticate your usage of the YouTube Data API.

In return, the server returns tokens, in the form of an Access Token and Refresh Token. These tokens are need to refresh the ability to use the API without expiry.

However, I was receiving (Object, object) in the terminal when requesting the 'tokens'....

Logger.log(`Got the tokens:(token)`);

To rectify the problem and reveal the tokens in the terminal in a readable string format, I done the following...

Logger.log(`Got the tokens: ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);

Now I can use the tokens accordingly.

//Note - ES6 backticks are used as string literals, but the backticks don't seem to be displaying in the parameters.

Comment: Why not include a snippet of code and associated output that demonstrates this?

Comment: Yes sure, I've edited my answer to include further information.